# setting check box values in jquery

Tags: jquery

In my page I have an array of check boxes(4 check boxes). By default they have no values set. If two of the check boxes are checked and then I submit the page, then the checkbox array I am getting [on,on]. But I need it like ['YES','YES','NO','NO']. But I am failing to set the values of the check boxes. Plz help. Below is my code,

```
$('input[name$="chkIndex"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('checked')){
                  $(this).val='YES';
                }else{
                  $(this).val='NO';
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`val()` is a method, you can try:

```
 $(this).val('YES');
```

```
$('input[name$="chkIndex"]').each(function(){
     if(this.checked){
         $(this).val('YES');
         // or this.value = "YES";
     } else {
         $(this).val('NO');
         // or this.value = "NO";
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But one problem. The valus are set 'YES' for checked and 'NO' for unchecked, but when the page is submitted only it becomes['YES','YES'], instead of ['YES','YES','NO','NO'].

Comment: @SweetDream You are welcome, what is the type of the input elements?

Comment: These are input type='checkbox'. May be when the page is submitted the unchecked check boxes are not subnitted as DOM objects. Thats why I am not getting them in the action class.

Comment: @SweetDream are you sure that your markup is valid and your selector selects all of them?

Comment: They are not all selected. Among the four checkboxes 2 are selected and two are not. So I need them as ['YES','YES','NO','NO']. But the unchecked boxes are not added in the array after the page submit.

Comment: I found it, that in struts the only values of selected checkboxes will be trunsmitted when the form is submitted. refer: http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/userGuide/struts-html.html#checkbox I wonder if the unchecked values can be sent also.